# Get YouTube video id in Python

Tags: python, youtube-api, data-science

I am working on a project for my MSc class and I have users that have declared songs they like in youtube, creating a large data-set. I have found a way to get the video id of a song by searching with you-tube-api, but it seems that the key they provide has an access limit. The code is bellow:

```
api_key = 'xxxxxxxx'
yt = YouTubeDataAPI(api_key)
searches = yt.search(q=song,
                 max_results=1)
yt.get_video_metadata_gen(searches[0]['video_id'])
```

Do you know any alternative way to do it without a limit? 
I guess there should be an option to provide keys without limitations for research purposes or to universities, but I am not able to find sth like this.

Comment: _I have users that have declared songs they like in youtube, creating a large data-set._ What kind of information do you have on the songs? Links?

Comment: No, just song and artist. This is why I need to get the video id

Comment: _No, just song and artist._ How do you identify the correct video using only that?

Comment: I just need the audio, by simply keeping the first valid video_id. So it could be any video of the selected song

Comment: _So it could be any video of the selected song_ Alright, that should make things much easier, right?